# ffmpeg need to run this command for 360 times

Tags: android, ffmpeg

`FFmpeg` need to run this command for `360` times but it fails after `200`
or any optimization for this command.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
     commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/bgimage.jpg -i /sdcard/videokit/disk_round.png - 
     filter_complex [1:v]scale=800:800,setsar=1,rotate=" +
     i + "*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)[s];[0][s]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[out] -pix_fmt bgra - 
     strict experimental -s 720x720 -map [out] /sdcard/videokit/image-spin/"+ i + ".png";

     vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());
}
```